# What is this coaxial RF connector?

Tags: rf, identification, connector, radio, wifi

This thing appears on some ASUS motherboard and I could not find out its name.

Diameter is about 4.5mm. I need to find its proper mating part to convert this stupid thing to SMA.

I prefer not to de-solder the entire module to replace it.

[image]

[image]

Compare it with the 3.5mm jack. It's very small.

**UPDATE:
Confirmed, it's female MMCX**

Comment: Regular RP-SMA?

Comment: Its hard to see from here.. How is it compared to SMA?

Comment: @EugeneSh. it's much smaller than SMA

Comment: From the datasheet:
http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/e7153_wi-fi_go_card.pdf
it says MMCX.  I've never seen threaded MMCX but apparently it exists:
https://www.digikey.com/catalog/en/partgroup/mmcx/90732

Edit: that looks like it might be RP-MMCX threaded - they really don't want you connecting anything but the supplied antennas to that!

Comment: @vir I doubt it's RP-MMCX because it has a hole in the middle. ASUS does not even sell replacement antenna. I'll try it with MMCX plug tomorrow.

Comment: @vir the threads are for panel mounting, not for cable attachment

Comment: this may help ... https://rog.asus.com/forum/showthread.php?88045-Replacement-antenna-for-Asus-quot-Wi-Fi-GO-quot-module

Comment: @jsotola ah that makes sense.

Comment: @vir If you post as answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @Davide_Andrea got to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a microwave connector. Given that it's panel mounted female, it should be one of [these](http://connectorbook.com/identification.html?st=1&nm=by_names&bm=by_compon&c=round_conn&u=coax_conn&o=microwave_conn&fl=00200020000000-c-%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C) (my site).

If you tell us the diameter, I should be able to narrow it down. If you show us a close-up, I should be able to tell how it's fastened. But, my guess is that it's an [MMCX](http://connectorbook.com/identification.html?st=1&nm=by_names&bm=by_compon&c=round_conn&u=coax_conn&o=interior_rf_conn&f=blind_mate_rf_conn&s=MMCX):

https://www.digikey.se/short/zw8t0ww3

[image]